# Is it possible to remove the pronoun from the second clause in the following sentence?

Tags: grammar, reference

Please consider the following sentence:

> Therefore they can become bad-tempered easily when they face a
> problem.

Is it ok If I remove the second they?

> Therefore they can become bad-tempered easily when face a
> problem.

Which one is clearer and more natural?

Comment: I think it is better to use "in facing a problem" instead of "when ...'.

Comment: It isn't OK to remove the second 'they' unless you change it to _...when facing a problem._